# boost log rotate_file raise error when trying to rotate empty file?

Tags: c++, boost-log

I am using boost log and every period i manually change log file so i need to use rotate_file.
when there is logs in file every thing works fine.
when the file is empty but i need to close it and open next one ,rotate_file give error related to file system????
how can i rotate file which is empty???
i need to use `rotate_file` on locked_backend having empty file without any logs.
i tried to `locked_backend->close_file()` but it gives error due to being private to backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you haven't written any log records, and there wasn't a previous log file with a name matching the filename pattern you set, there isn't any log file (i.e. it's not an empty file, but there is no file at all). In that case rotating the file manually will throw, indicating a failure. It is up to you how to deal with that exception. You can ignore it if you want to.

Comment: i debugged this rotate_file and found it is consume member of back end which open file. i found file predicate to indicate the presence of file. ill use this to avoid rotating non existant files..i also tried to open file for the back end but i could not find a way to control consume member of back end